# Katalon counting the conditional statements that goes into else block, into failure

Tags: xpath, automated-tests, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I recently started using the Katalon Studio, for automation. While writing the scripts I checked if an object is present or not on the DOM by using:

```
if(findTestObject('{Object ID}')){
  //do some work
} else{
  //do another work
}
```

if the object is found it's all good, but if it isn't, it continues executing in the else block, but in failure log it shows it as a failure. I've tried implementing some of the solutions to fix it that were on the [**Katalon discussion page**](https://forum.katalon.com/), but none of them worked.

Is there any way to stop counting the else block code into failure?

Answer (score 1):

Recommended way is using [Verify Element Present](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/webui-verify-element-present.html#description). Try changing your script to:

```
if(WebUI.verifyElementPresent(findTestObject('{Object ID}'), 5)){
  //do some work
} else{
  //do another work
}
```

(in this example, '5' is the timeout you expect to find the element in, lower it if needed).

I believe this happens because `findTestObject` only returns reference to object in Object Repository but does not guarantee the element is really loaded in DOM.

Comment: This is what to do, however, you forgot the `FailureHandling`.... it should be either `FailureHandling.CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE` if you want a warning for that condition, or `FailureHandling.OPTIONAL` if it has no bearing on the test case results.